# Unknown ordinal value for enum class

Tags: java, hibernate, enums

Hi am getting the below error whille trying to do some changes in my application.
Can you please help me to resolve the same. have tried to find the same on onlinebut nothing help.

error Stack:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Unknown ordinal value for enum class entity.beschikking.BeschikkingStatus$BeschikkingStatusType: 5; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown ordinal value for enum class entity.beschikking.BeschikkingStatus$BeschikkingStatusType: 5] with root cause
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown ordinal value for enum class entity.beschikking.BeschikkingStatus$BeschikkingStatusType: 5
at org.hibernate.type.EnumType.nullSafeGet(EnumType.java:112)
```

class:

```
 @org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage =CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "beschikking_statussen", schema = "lgr")
 public class BeschikkingStatus implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@Column(unique = true, insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false)
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private BeschikkingStatusType id;

public BeschikkingStatusType getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(BeschikkingStatusType id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public enum BeschikkingStatusType {
    ONBEKEND,
    VOORLOPIG,
    DEFINITIEF,
    DEFINITIEF_CORRIGEREN,
    GEARCHIVEERD;
}

}
```

Comment: What did you change?

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to get `BeschikkingStatusType: 5`, but that doesn't exist because the enum only has 5 values and it starts counting at 0.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you have removed an item from your `enum BeschikkingStatusType` during re-factoring, but some of the saved data has rows referencing the old value. You need to remove or change this data manually in order to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Code seems fine, do you have existing data?

If yes, there probably is some data with value 5 and that is why you get an error.

Answer (score 0):

When you have existing data with enum ordinals, you cannot delete values or change their order, you can only add new values at the end. If a certain value need not be used any more, tag it @Deprecated in the enum but do not remove it.